# Spring Data JPA não reconhece o comando SQL 'Limit'?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, spring-data, h2database

Estou criando uma API REST, utilizando Spring Boot, que, usando dados de uma tabela, exibe frases aleatórias.

Dando um Google, descobri que é possível gerar resultados aleatórios através de SQL puro:

```sql
SELECT <coluna> FROM <tabela> ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

Fiz a consulta do Banco H2, que é o banco que estou usando, e funcionou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que o Spring Data não reconhece o comando SQL `LIMIT`. Quando crio a query dentro do repositório, através desse código:

```java
public interface QuoteRepository extends JpaRepository<Quote, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT detail FROM Quote ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
    Quote findByQuote();

    Quote findByActor(String actor);
}
```

Recebo a seguinte exceção:

> unexpected token: LIMIT near line 1, column 54 [SELECT detail FROM challenge.Quote ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1]

***Observação:*** a tabela scripts é mapeada pelo classe de domínio `Quote`.

Alguém sabe de algum comando que possa substituir `LIMIT`?

**Código completo no [GitHub](https://github.com/vanribeiro/gerador-de-frases-aleatorias).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso esteja com o mesmo problema, encontrei [essa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279186/fetch-random-records-using-spring-data-jpa) e adaptei ao meu problema e funcionou. Ele usa paginação, conforme sugerido pelo Marciano Machado, em uma das respostas acima.

Devido a forma como desafio foi enviado, bem como os testes unitários que foram escritos anteriormente, e pré formatados, precisava que manter o método original e que ele retornasse um único objeto.

Sendo assim, modifiquei o repositório para sobrescrever o método do JPA, `findAll()`, para que recebesse um objeto `Pageable` e usei, também, o método `count()`. O repositório, ficou assim:

```
long count();
Page<Quote> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

Na classe que implementa o serviço, o código ficou assim:

```
public Quote getQuote() {
        long countIds = repository.count();
        int idRandom = (int)(Math.random() * countIds);
        Page<Quote> quotePage = repository.findAll(PageRequest.of(idRandom, 1)); 
        Quote quote = null;
        if(quotePage.hasContent()) {
            quote = quotePage.getContent().get(0);
        }
        return quote;
    }
```

Essencialmente, ele usa o repositório para contar a quantidade de `IDs`, na tabela, e utiliza esse resultado para multiplicar pelo valor gerado pelo método `random()` da classe `Math`.

Depois a busca é feita e guardada em `quotePage`, utilizando o `ID` aleatório (`idRandom`), limitando ele a uma página apenas.

E, então, ele verifica: se existir conteúdo, `quote` recebe esse conteúdo e o retorna ao método `getQuote()`, senão, ele retorna `quote` como nulo.

Comment: Edite sua resposta e coloque o código que você criou. Vai ajudar outros usuários.

Comment: Código adicionado.

Answer (score 3):

Olá, o spring, utiliza do JPA, que por sua vez utiliza a linguagem JPQL para consultas, que é uma linguagem similar ao SQL só que utiliza da abordagem objeto-relacional.

O JPQL não implementa o comando limit, uma vez que o JPQL tenta abordar todos os bancos relacionais, e cada banco implementa o limit de sua forma, e alguns não implementa, o JPQL não implementa o limit.

Utilizando JPQL e spring você pode utilizar paginação, conforme abaixo:

```
public interface QuoteRepository extends JpaRepository<Quote, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT detail FROM Quote ORDER BY RANDOM()")
    List<String> findByQuote(Pageable pageable);

}
```

Em seu service você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
Pageable primeiroResultado = new PageRequest(0, 1);
List<String> result = repository.findByQuote(primeiroResultado);
```

Comment: Marciano, muito obrigada por responder!  Só tenho uma dúvida:  a paginação precisa ser um em `list`?  Pelo código que sugeriu usar no `service`, meu método teria de retornar `result`. O problema é que na interface `QuoteService` foi estabelecido que o método deve ser `Quote getQuote()` e, é implementado na classe `QuoteServiceImpl`, deve retornar um objeto Quote, o que significa, no meu entendimento, não retornar uma lista... Existe alguma forma? 

Comment: Não resolve seu problema iterar a lista, alimentar um objeto `Quote` com o registro encontrado e retornar esse `Quote` no seu método?

Comment: @StatelessDev,  Até tentei usar aqui, mas o preciso que o método seja do `Quote findByName();`. A lista que está sendo iterada é do tipo String. Mesmo que eu use `List<Quote> result`, ainda estará retornando uma lista do tipo Quote e não um objeto Quote. Posso estar errada, mas é assim que entendo o retorno de um método. A Interface já veio criada e preciso segui o padrão do projeto.

Comment: Marciano, uma pessoa enviou [um link da documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_native_queries) do `Spring Data` e também [essa outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287426/corresponding-spring-jpa-method-name-for-requesting-a-random-row-in-sql/43290267#43290267), para o uso de `native queries` e o compilador aceitou e o erro. Agora estou com outro problema...  Ele não está reconhecendo o `id`... Acho vou abrir outra pergunta para isso...

Comment: Sim, abra outra pergunta detalhando o erro.

Comment: Buscando solução, [encontrei uma pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279186/fetch-random-records-using-spring-data-jpa), usando paginação como me sugeriu, conforme você me sugeriu, mas usando Page no lugar de Pageable. Vou postar a solução aqui, caso tenha gente com mais problemas. Adaptei ao meu problema e funcionou e também, com isso, resolveu o problema do ID. Mesmo assim, muito obrigada pela disponibilidade. 

Comment: Só mais uma coisa, caso alguém que esteja lendo essa resposta e esteja pensando em usar o construtor `PageRequest`, ele foi descontinuado. Ao invés dele, pode ser utilizado `PageRequest.of(int page, int size)`, [conforme conta na documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html#of-int-int-).

Answer (score 1):

Outra opção se você estiver utilizando jpa 1.7 + é mudar a nomenclatura do método usando top ou first, exemplo:

```
 @Query("SELECT detail FROM Quote ORDER BY RANDOM(")
    Quote findTop1ByQuote();

 @Query("SELECT detail FROM Quote ORDER BY RANDOM()")
    Quote findFirstByQuote();
```

Comment: Obrigada por responder, Lucas! Mas infelizmente as duas não deram certo. Recebo essa mensagem:  `query did not return a unique result: 18307`.