# Como resolver: Column "id" not found [42122-197]?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

Gente, estou criando uma API que irá exibir frases aleatórias, a partir de uma tabela no banco de dados.

O problema é que sempre que acesso a rota, no console, recebo essa exceção:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "id" not found [42122-197]

E no Postman:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-11-01T00:47:59.559+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "could not execute query; SQL [SELECT detail FROM scripts ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query",
    "path": "/v1/quote"
}
```

Estou utilizando o banco é o H2. Na pasta `resources`, existe um arquivo `schema.sql`, que contem a SQL para a tabela, e um `data.sql`, com a carga de dados.

Só que o ID existe na tabela `scripts`, dentro de `schema.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE scripts (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  /* mais código*/
);
```

E existe na classe `Quote`, que deve mapear a classe a tabela `scripts`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="scripts")
public class Quote {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

        /*Outra variáveis*/      

       /*Getters e Setters*/
}
```

Agora não sei se não consegui mapear a tabela corretamente...

O mapeamento dessa tabela deveria ser automático, certo?

Projeto completo no [GitHub](https://github.com/vanribeiro/gerador-de-frases-aleatorias).

Comment: A tabela está sendo criada corretamente?

Comment: Oi, @LeonardoLima! Obrigada por comentar! Então, pelo que entendi sim, quando entro no console H2, a tabela está e está populada com os dados de `data.sql`.

Comment: @LeonardoLima, o problema foi resolvido. Mudei a forma de fazer a pesquisa. Modifiquei para paginação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gente, o problema foi resolvido. Se estiver tendo um problema similar, resolvi depois que fiz algumas modificações, conforme constam nessa outra pergunta que fiz aqui no PTSO:
[Spring Data JPA não reconhece o comando SQL 'Limit'?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/340118/spring-data-jpa-n%C3%A3o-reconhece-o-comando-sql-limit)